# Multiple WHERE conditions in 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have 2 tables as follows:

**table1**

```
ID    Name     Test
A011  John     1
A012  Lynda    1
A013  Micheal  1
A014  Jack     0
A021  Joe      1
A015  Paul     0
```

**table2**

```
ID    Done
A011  1
A012  1
```

I want to select all rows from **table1** that have an `ID` where the 3 first letters are equal to `A01`, and the `test` field is `1`, and also the `ID` is not present in **table2**.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE a.test = 1 AND b.ID IS NULL
```

The result from that is 2 rows with `ID` `A013` and `A021`. I tried to use `LEFT(ID,3)` to get the `ID` with `A01`, however, I couldn't achieve what I want.

How can I filter only the records where the ID starts with `A01`?

Comment: Welll... Did you tried something? `Inner join` could help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question adding the query you have by now.

Comment: @GustavoStraube, I edited my question, please have a look. Thank you

Comment: Try to add this condition to your `WHERE` clause: `a.ID LIKE 'A01%'`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Thank you very much, it worked well. Thank you!!!! If I want to add ORDER BY and LIMIT, it's still working?

Comment: Yes. It's also supposed to work with ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you the desired result

SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid WHERE LEFT(t1.userid , 3) LIKE '%A01%' AND t1.userid NOT IN (SELECT userid from table2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE test = 1 
AND ID LIKE "AO1%"
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID from table2)
```